# Angular Apollo Codegen returning intellisense for anonymous object

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I am evaluating the usage of GraphQL with Angular. I am able to successfully scaffold the schema using the `@graphql-codegen` package. And the generated services work in querying the database.

However, I have realised that the results of the queries are in an unexpected shape, at least for. Don't get me wrong everything is strongly-typed. But it appears, that the intellisense is returning strongly-typed `anonymous objects` (like in C#)..

For example let's look at this GraphQL Query

```
query Animals {
  animals {
    id
    name
    latinName
    created
    changed
    changedBy
  }
}
```

When run against the Database this returns the following JSON

```json
{
    "data": {
        "animals": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Rehwild",
                "latinName": "Capreolus capreolus",
                "created": "2023-04-01T19:29:45.513Z",
                "changed": "2023-04-01T19:29:45.513Z",
                "changedBy": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Dammwild",
                "latinName": "Dama dama",
                "created": "2023-04-01T19:29:45.513Z",
                "changed": "2023-04-01T19:29:45.513Z",
                "changedBy": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With the codegen, I would have expected that in the data property of the response the apollo client would return to me `Animal[]` with something like the following interface:

```js
export interface Animal {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    latinName: string;
    created: string;
    changed: string;
    changedBy: string;
}
```

And in fact, in the generated TS code, there is (even with two more properties I have not requested in above graphQL query):

```js
/** A specific animal that can be searched for and saved. */
export type Animal = {
  __typename?: 'Animal';
  changed: Scalars['DateTime'];
  changedBy: Scalars['String'];
  created: Scalars['DateTime'];
  id: Scalars['Int'];
  latinName?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  name: Scalars['String'];
  timesDied: Array<Death>;
  timesRescued: Array<Rescue>;
};
```

So, when I try to load the data in the ctor of my component:

```js
  constructor(private animals: AnimalsGQL) {
    this.animals$ = this.animals.watch().valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.animals));
  }
```

I am getting a return type of the following screenshot, instead of Animal[].

[image]

Using the description of the type is a problem in all other parts of the code, because I really would have expected to reference the type directly and not to reference a description of an `anonymous type`. Does someone know, why this is happening? I have included details of my setup and the codegen config.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "codegen": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.13",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^15.4.0",
    "apollo-angular": "^4.2.1",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "3.3.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "3.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular": "3.5.6",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

codegen.ts

```js
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: "https://localhost:7029/graphql",
  documents: "src/**/*.graphql",
  generates: {
    "src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts": {
      plugins: ['typescript', 'typescript-operations', 'typescript-apollo-angular'],
      config: {
        addExplicitOverride: true
      }
    },
    "./graphql.schema.json": {
      plugins: ["introspection"]
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not have a concept of "anonymous types".
Most of the time, interfaces are referenced by name in tooltips, and types are inlined in tooltips, but even that isn't always the case. Sometimes TypeScript just does it the other way round.

In the end, this is what you see in a tooltip, and has no influence over the behaviour of TypeScript. No matter if it is inlined or not, this will be treated 100% equivalently by TypeScript and has no consequences anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you. That was insightful.  Accepting it the way it is, I "worked-around" it by just casting the array elements to Animal in a map function

Comment: But why do you need to cast them? TypeScript is "duck-typed". If it looks like a duck, and walks like a duck, it's a duck - what you show in your screenshot up there **is the `Animal` type** - just expanded by TypeScript. That expanded type can 100% always be used everywhere the Animal type could be used. No casting needed - internally those two are the same anyways!

Comment: The reason for the cast is, that I have methods expecting an input parameter of type `Animal`. However, without the cast it is of type `{ id: number, name: string, .... }` which I cannot pass to the method expecting an `Animal` object. At least VS code is complaining about it and angular won't compile. Also I just realised, that casting creates its own problems in this case. Because the type `Animal` has `timeRescued` and `timesDied` properties, which I _can_ request in an Animal query, but I did _not_ in this case... so if not being careful, this will lead to null exceptions, right?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have that type `Animal`, that you didn't request from the server in the first place - and obviously, that doesn't match your server response. Maybe you shouldn't use that type, because it seems to describe the full `Animal` type that the server offers, not any type that would actually be used in your application?

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was wrongly assuming the codegen plugin would create models of the queries I explicitly specify (and not what the server is offering). But in fact it is the opposite. The queries I specify will be used to create strongly-typed services to do CRUD operations

Comment: Depending on how you configure the codegen, it will do both: create types for all the "full schema types" *and* specific types for your query. You'll have to play with the codegen a bit, it has a myriad of options.

Comment: Hey @phry, thanks for the pointer. I had a look at the config, but unfortunately I was unable to find a setting to also generate types of the queries (and not only what the server is offering). Maybe [this, `documentMode`](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-apollo-angular#documentmode), but I don't understand the description.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not an Angular user, so I can't tell you anything about the Angular-related codegen, I'm sorry.

Comment: Please don't apologise. You have helped me a lot already. Thank you!